# Distribution of ordered random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, order-statistics

Let $\Phi$ be a homogeneous PPP of intensity $\lambda$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Let {$x_0, x_1, \dotsc$} $= \Phi~\cap~\mathbb{R}^+$, in increasing order, i.e., $0 < x_0 < x_1 < \dotsc$. I want to find the complementary cumulative distribution function (CCDF) of $x_0/x_k$, where $x_k$ is Erlang distributed with pdf $f_{x_k}(x) = \frac{\lambda^{k+1}x^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda x}$.

Comment: $x_i$ are values of the process at certain times, or the times when the jumps occur?

Comment: $x_i$ are the points of the homogeneous PPP in one dimension.

Comment: I don't understand what "points" means (maybe this is standard terminology but I'm not familiar with it). To me you have a process that jumps from state $k$ to state $k+1$ at a random time $t_{k+1}$. Do you mean that your $x_k$ are what I'm calling $t_k$?

Comment: Yes. We can consider $x_k$ as an arrival time, which is distributed according to Poisson distribution with intensity $\lambda$.

Comment: OK. Then the increments are each exponentially distributed with mean $1/\lambda$ and are independent. So the quantity you want is $\frac{X}{X+Y}$ where $X$ is Exp($1/\lambda$), $Y$ is Gamma($k,1/\lambda$) and the two are independent. (Here I am using the "shape,scale" convention for the Gamma distribution, as Wikipedia describes it.) It seems to me that it should be relatively straightforward to compute the CDF in this situation; $\frac{X}{X+Y} \leq q$ if and only if $X \leq q(X+Y)$ if and only if $Y \geq \frac{X}{1-q}$ (interpreting $X/0$ as $+\infty$).

Comment: I think $X$ and $Y$ are dependent RVs. Because, $x_k$ cannot occur unless $x_0$ has occurred.

Comment: $X$ and $X+Y$ are dependent but $X$ and $Y$ are not. $Y$ here is $x_k-x_0$ in your notation.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer! Since we have a homogeneous PPP, the random variables $x_0/x_i$ with $i = 1, 2, \dotsc$ are uniformly distributed in the interval (0, 1). Also, since $x_1 < x_2 < \dotsc < x_k$, we have $x_0/x_1 > x_0/x_2 > \dotsc > x_0/x_k$. Thus, 
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{x_0}{x_k} > \theta \right) = \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{x_0}{x_1} > \theta, \frac{x_0}{x_2} > \theta, \dotsc, \frac{x_0}{x_{k-1}} > \theta\right).$$

Since $x_0/x_i$ are independent random variables, we have
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{x_0}{x_k} > \theta \right) = (1-\theta)^{k-1}.$$

Comment: That first thing doesn't sound right...$x_0/x_i$ should get smaller as $i$ increases, and the $x_0/x_i$ shouldn't be independent either.